# Python Multiprocessing - handle exceptions from child process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

1. The main process does the task scheduling, and the child process does the task execution.
2. The child process needs to return key progress information, and the main process gets that progress information.
3. If there is an exception during the execution of the child process, the main process needs to catch it and terminate itself.

I would like to ask how to use **Python** to do this? maybe by `multiprocessing` module or `multiprocessing.Pool`?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Possibly duplicates: [How to detect exceptions in concurrent.futures in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33448329), [Python multiprocessing: how to exit cleanly after an error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23716951), [Exception thrown in multiprocessing Pool not detected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6728236), [Python multiprocessing and handling exceptions in workers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16943404)

Comment: Pay attention on parallelbar
https://pypi.org/project/parallelbar

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html).  When you fetch the result of a future, if a child thread/process had an exception it will be raised in the thread fetching the result of the future.

I have used [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) below but [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) works as well.  You can catch the exception and continue processing as shown:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time

def task(n):
    if n == 5:
        raise ValueError('5 exception')
    else:
        time.sleep(2)
    return n

# 'if' line needed by ProcessPoolExecutor on some OSes.  Always use for portability.
# Not needed for ThreadPoolExecutor.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(task, value) for value in range(10)]
        for future in futures:
            try:
                print(future.result())
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5 exception
6
7
8
9
```